# MySQL - SQL query to get the customer ids and date of 20th transaction

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble coming up with a query to get a list of customer ids and the date of their 20th purchase.

I am given a table called transactions with the column name customer_id and purchase_date. Each row in the table is equal to one transaction.

| customer_id | purchase_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-11-19 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 |
| 3 | 2021-12-05 |
| 3 | 2021-12-09 |
| 3 | 2021-12-16 |

I tried to do it like this and assumed I would have to count the number of times the customer_id has been mentioned and return the id number if the count equals 20.

```
SELECT customer_id, MAX(purchase_date)
FROM transactions
(
     SELECT customer_id,
     FROM transactions
     GROUP BY customer_id
     HAVING COUNT (customer_id) =20
)
```

How can I get this to return the list of customer_id and only the date of the 20th transaction?

Comment: Please add some data and expected result in text format. And more important what `MySQL` version are you using ?

Comment: Just added some data, the text format would just be the same table but only lists the customer_id once and the 20th purchase date next to it. MySQL 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the rows of transactions belonging to the customer_id and filter the result by the 20th row

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT customer_id, purchase_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY customer_id
        ORDER BY purchase_date DESC
    ) AS nth
    FROM transactions
) as t WHERE nth = 20
```

Comment: When a customer has 21 (or any count() other than 20)  transactions, will it be in the results? (I think not)

Comment: I only need the list of customer id and date of their 20th purchase, it doesn't matter if they have more

Comment: @Luuk I see my bad, will change it

Comment: @Luuk you haven't  carefully read the  question ? `I am having trouble coming up with a query to get a list of customer ids and the date of their 20th purchase` . Only the 20th purchase is needed no more, no less

Comment: i did read the question, and I think, when a customer has more than 20 transaction the interest is only for the 20th transaction.

Comment: I hope @Steve does to his edit soon. so I can undo the downvote.....   (I did get hist attention anyway)

Comment: Yes @Luuk I have updated the answer now

Answer (score 0):

Use row_number = 20

```
SELECT 
  customer_id,
  purchase_date as date_t_20
FROM 
(
     SELECT  
       customer_id,
       purchase_date,
       Row_number() OVER (
         PARTITION BY customer_id 
          ORDER BY purchase_date) AS rn
     FROM transactions
) T
WHERE rn = 20;
```

Comment: By including row number, would this not mean that there is only one customer id?

Comment: Currently you are selecting `purchase_date` from a table (`T`) which does have have a field `purchase_date`.

Comment: @Luuk corrected : thank you

Comment: `Row_number() over (partition by` will give a new series for each partition, in this case each customer_id, so there will be a `rn = 20` for each customer_id having 20 or more transactions

Comment: Thanks for you time to correct this. It makes stackoverflow a better place when only tested responses are given,  I Personally hate the "try this:" answers (even from myself )

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
select *
from transactions t
inner join (
   select 
      customer_id,
      purchase_date,
      row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by purchase_date) R
   from transactions) x on x.purchase_date=t.purchase_date
                       and x.customer_id=t.customer_id
where x.R=20;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6507ddfb72a953a5df57379bf7358c6)

For MySQL5.7, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ad6fb4a0ef173205367f10efe0f5accf)

```
set @r:=1;
select *
from transactions t
inner join (
   select 
      customer_id,
      purchase_date,
      @r:=@r+1 R
   from transactions) x on x.purchase_date=t.purchase_date
                       and x.customer_id=t.customer_id
where x.R=20;
```

Comment: I see that this returns an additional column R which shows the row number?

Comment: You can do `SELECT customer_id, purchase_date, customer_id, purchase_date`, in stead of `SELECT *`